# Weird fragment on Mocha JS test page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tdd, mocha.js

I'm trying out [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) for my JS testing, and I'm getting this weird fragment:

[image: weird fragment]

Oddly, the [tutorial](http://www.joeytrapp.com/posts/mocha-js-tests-from-command-line) I'm following also has this fragment in his screenshots, yet the author makes no mention of anything being awry. I'm using Chrome 18. I can't seem to find this anywhere in the web inspector either...

Anyone know what's up with this? Driving me nuts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some UTF-8 being interpreted in another charset (probably Latin-1).  Try setting your browser's encoding to UTF-8—do you see something more useful? (Probably a checkmark: ✔)

**Edit**: yes, it's the UTF-8 encoding of "✔" interpreted as Latin-1.  You may need to add a `<meta charset="utf8">` to the top of your `<head>`.